# SQL Syntax Error when calling PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have some PowerShell code that I use in a SQL Server Agent Job. The Job itself connects to an FTP Site And pulls down all the file names in a specific directory.

The PowerShell Works fine when run through PowerShell ISE with no errors but when it is run in SQL it throws a syntax error.

The offending line is the first line which is

```
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$($Server)$($Directory)")
```

I have done some research and found that SQL doesn't like the `$($` and to remove the first 2 characters `$(`. However this doesn't work because there is another which follows immediately (I removed those too) and now the code runs but does nothing at all.

The error that shows in the job history is

```
Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(8): Syntax error).  The step failed.
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work in SQL?

Comment: How exactly are you running this in/through Sql?

Comment: In a SQL Agent Job step

Comment: This might be an esoteric agent problem. See similar a question on [DBA.so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58679). If that's not the case, please add more details like the exact error message and MCVE maybe too.

Comment: I take it the step type is set to powershell? Do you have any other steps that execute powershell scripts? If not have you tested another one that does something very basic to see if that runs/works (maybe write to a log file or update a file on disk, something simple)?

Comment: The type is set to PowerShell. There isn't any other on this Server that run PowerShell but I have just run it on a server where I know PowerShell steps run with no issues and it has given me the same error

Comment: Try this `$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$Server$Directory")`

Comment: Brilliant. If you post it as an answer i'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subexpression operator `$()` is unnecessary within this string as PowerShell will expand the two variables to strings correctly without it:

```
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$Server$Directory")
```

Answer (score 3):

You receive the error itself because of SQL Server Agent [user tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps). SQL Server Agent treats `$()` as a special character sequence and when found will try to resolve the value inside to a specific user token. Since one does not match you are getting a syntax error. Obviously PowerShell treats this sequence in a completely different manner, therefore running the same code in the ISE returns no error.

The easy answer is when it comes to using PowerShell in SQL Server Agent job steps you cannot use sub-expression syntax in your code. You will need to re-code it. [A bit more background on my experience with it.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/58669/507)